# DataContext binding evaluated after property binding -- causes crash

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I'm trying to set the DataContext of several toggle buttons, each of which will correspond to a particular element of a list.  These toggle buttons are static, not dynamically generated, because we wanted to group them in the layout, and not have them all in one area.

`ListOfRoles` is a collection of objects, each of which has an `IsSelected` property (type `bool?`) and a name.  The `nameToObject` converter returns the object with the name given in the converter.

**My problem** is that XAML is trying to bind `IsSelected` before it has evaluated the DataContext binding, which throws an exception on our system.  It tries to bind to the object which `RoleContainerStyle` is applied to, and crashes.  Here is the XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="RoleContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyListBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyListBoxItem}">
        <Grid>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <ToggleButton Content="Driver To Scene"   IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" DataContext="{Binding ListOfRoles, Converter={StaticResource nameToObject}, ConverterParameter='Driver To'}"    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"       Width="80" Height="40" FontSize="14.667" />
            <ToggleButton Content="Driver From Scene" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" DataContext="{Binding ListOfRoles, Converter={StaticResource nameToObject}, ConverterParameter='Driver From'}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8,0,0,0" Width="80" Height="40" FontSize="14.667" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I put breakpoints in the converter and verified that it *DOES NOT* enter the converter before trying to evaluate the `IsSelected` binding.

If I remove the `IsSelected` binding, I *AM* able to trap execution within the converter, so it seems like a problem with order of evaluation, unless I am missing something about XAML.

I have tried changing the order of the properties in XAML, tried using the long form of specifying Bindings (nested tags), and I am just out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to specify DataContext for **ToggleButton** only for **IsSelected** property, and if your list is always contain 2 items, you can use this (don't tested, but I hope you get the idea):

```
<Style x:Key="RoleContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyListBoxItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyListBoxItem}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ToggleButton Content="Driver To Scene"   IsChecked="{Binding ListOfRoles[0].IsSelected}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"       Width="80" Height="40" FontSize="14.667" />
        <ToggleButton Content="Driver From Scene" IsChecked="{Binding ListOfRoles[1].IsSelected}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8,0,0,0" Width="80" Height="40" FontSize="14.667" />
      </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

Remark: do not use one layout control for another layout control. (**StackPanel** inside **Grid**)

Comment: What we ended up doing was implementing the [] indexer with a string for the name, and refactoring the xaml to use it.  The list contains more than two items, and we don't control the numerical indexing (b/c of NHibernate).